# Pear outputs IS_VAR

Tags: php, macos, pear

If I use pear from comandline i get strange output "IS_VAR" (whatever pear comands, php unit test's)

example "pear list"

```
IS_VAR

IS_VAR

IS_VAR

IS_VAR

IS_VAR

IS_VAR
Installed packages, channel pear.php.net:
=========================================
Package          Version State
Archive_Tar      1.3.7   stable
Console_Getopt   1.3.0   stable
PEAR             1.9.1   stable
PHP_CodeSniffer  1.2.2   stable
PhpDocumentor    1.4.3   stable
Structures_Graph 1.0.4   stable
```

Any ideas to fix?

== update ==

I debugged pear script a bit. And I founded strange behavior

class PEAR_PackageFile, method factory

```
$version = $version{0};
```

and this line throws this error. I replaced to similar functionality

```
$version = substr($version,0,1);
```

and this output disappeared. Of course i hava same issue with some other places, like UnitTests. So question why this strange output is same mystery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling traces is NOT the answer as stack traces are one of the major useful features of xdebug. It was a problem with the xdebug package itself which has been fixed (see http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=756).

If you have a distribution copy of xdebug, you can install it from PECL (may require sudo/privilege escalation):

```
pecl install xdebug
```

Otherwise, you can upgrade it from PECL:

```
pecl upgrade xdebug
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `xdebug.auto_trace = 0` in your php.ini file. See [bug #18173](http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=18173).

Answer (score -1):

I think you have some debug output in your pear code, or maybe even some global php prepend file. The IS_VAR is NOT part of PEAR; you somehow added that yourself to the code.

Comment: I founded line which throws this strange output. Something mysterious stays.